# Yii2 creating simple singleton

Tags: yii2, singleton

I am trying to create simple singleton in yii2 contoller. Maybe i misunderstood something about this pattern but i decide to try. So i have a CRUD. When i got one instance of that class in the db and i decide to update it, the `$instance` variable is empty(null). Is it because of the page reloading after the creation of the instance and that's why my static variable is set to null again? And is it even possible to make it like this or i am really, really on wrong way? Thank you in advance!

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use backend\models\DeliveryTime;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use Yii;

class DeliveryTimeController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

    public static $instance = null;

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $delivery = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => DeliveryTime::find()->where('id>0')
        ]);
        return $this->render('index', ['delivery' => $delivery]);
    }

    public static function setInstance()
    {
        if(self::$instance == null){
            self::$instance = new DeliveryTime();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $delivery = DeliveryTimeController::setInstance();

        if($delivery->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $delivery->save()){
            self::$instance = $delivery;
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

        return $this->render('create', ['model' => $delivery]);
    }

    public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $delivery = DeliveryTimeController::getInstance();

        if($delivery->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $delivery->save()){
            return $this->render(['index']);
        }
        return $this->render('update', ['model' => $delivery]);
    }

    public function actionDelete(){
        $delivery = DeliveryTimeController::getInstance();
        if($delivery != null){
            $delivery->delete();
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For design patterns i would recommend to check out

- https://github.com/kamranahmedse/design-patterns-for-humans
- https://github.com/edin/php-design-patterns  (my github repo :)

For what you are trying it's better to just create new instance.

Comment: Thank you! Will take a look!